# Aren't answers to "parsing XHTML with RegEx" misleading?

Tags: discussion

I am talking about [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) which is one of the very popular question on SO.

While the answers are made somewhat in jest but it lets a newbie believe that using RegEx on HTML is the evilest thing one can do. The third answer even gives a theoretical approach to it which is fairly wrong as suggested by [Jeff Kaufman](http://www.jefftk.com/p/parsing-html-with-regular-expressions). At numerous times, I forced myself to deal with peculiarities of HTML, spend hours to get the XML parser correct to realize the advice I banked upon are not even factually correct.

Comment: No, they aren't.  Some are out of date, but none are absolutely misleading.  Using a regex to do anything remotely interesting with HTML is like using an industrial pneumatic wrench to drive in a staple.  Sure, you can make it work if the tool is elegant enough, but you're much better off with a staple gun.

Comment: @Charles: I don't want to turn this into a perpetual hot debate. But lets be rational here, its perfectly alright to user RegEx to parse HTML when doing the other will take hours and lets not forget HTML is not perfect XML considering ability of browsers to accept everything.

Comment: If you have an input you know to be a certain form that you need to extract something from, it's not only a good idea to use regex, it's the only sensible way.

Comment: See also [Please stop linking to the “Zalgo” / anti-Cthulhu regex rant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182189/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant), in which some of the answers discuss the quality of that question, and of [Regular expression pattern not matching anywhere in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string).

Comment: @Shubham, without getting into said debate, yes, it *can* be perfectly acceptable to use a regex like a scalpel to extract a particularly interesting bit from a chunk of HTML... but anything beyond that is where there be dragons.  It's best to not try to teach people how to slay dragons with the wrong tools, for unwary developers are crunchy and taste good with ketchup.

Comment: Yes, it is extremely non-helpful to link to that posting instead of [trying to teach people how they could as well as when they should or should not try.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272)  ***Zalgo delenda est***.

Answer (score 8):

First of, the original question was about *X*HTML, not HTML in general. XHTML is XML. Parsers eat it happily. Browsers are not full of quirks that display it when broken.

However, the complaint here might be about people dup-ing questions about ordinary, crock-laden, HTML to the Zalgo question. Well, there are more choices than a picky parser or a regex. There are tools like jsoup and beautiful soup which are specifically designed to help disassemble HTML as found in the wild. There is simple procedural code to scrape out what's needed.

Html/Regex questions attract scorn (and Zalgo-links) because many (not all) of them are just bad questions. They show strong evidence of *cargo cult*-ism. They ask us to *send the codez*. More broadly, they show evidence that their authors have not learned their trade and don't care to learn their trade; they have heard a rumor that regexes are how you extract. If reading the Zalgo post causes them to stop and actually think, they might go on to learn something.

Comment: "Browsers are not full of quirks that display it when broken." ... when they're parsing and rendering it as XML anyway, which is almost *never*. Not completely relevant to the discussion at hand, but most of the time when you think you're perusing XHTML, you aren't really.

Comment: No, Zalgo doesn’t make people think.  Some it makes laugh; many it perplexes; but NOBODY does it help.  ***Zalgo delenda est.***